# Switching views does not switch controller in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, view

I have a simple angular app with that uses two templates and controllers.
Two buttons are placed to switch views.They call a function, defined within the controlles, which uses window.location='' to switch location.

However, if I place the ng-controller directive, the template changes but the controller does not.
But if I simply remove the ng-controller directive, no controller loads at all,but the default view is rendered.

What is going wrong??
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app='schoolConnect' ng-controller='takeCtrl' >
 <div ng-show='loading' style='margin-top:100px' >
<!--content-->
</div> 
<table width=40% align='center' style='margin-bottom:10px' >
  <tr>
   <td align='center' > 

 <!-- BUTTONS THAT SWITCH THE VIEW -->
  <div class='btn-group' > 
   <button class='btn btn-lg' ng-class='take_btn' ng-disabled='isTaking' ng-click='takeAttend()' >
&nbsp;Take&nbsp;
   </button>
   <button class='btn btn-lg' ng-class='view_btn' ng-disabled='isViewing'  ng-click='viewAttend()' >
&nbsp;View&nbsp;
  </button>

   </div>
   </td>
 </tr> 
</table>
<table width=40% align='center' >
   <!-- Some content that contains ng-models and ng-binds -->
</table>

<!-- This table Contains the rendered views -->
<table align='center' class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed" style='width:60%' ng-view></table>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
/*********************************
*>Apply controller to angular app**
 *>Define major functions **********
********************************/

//Initalize app
var app=angular.module('schoolConnect',['ngSanitize','ngRoute']);

//Define Views  

function configViews($routeProvider)
{
   $routeProvider
   //default view is Take Attendance
    .when('/take',{
      templateUrl: 'partials/takeAttendance.html', controller: "takeCtrl"
      })

     //View for tviewing attendance
     .when('/view',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/viewAttendance.html', controller: "viewCtrl"
        })

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/take'
       });
 }

 //Assign Views
  app.config(configViews);



//Assign controllers

//Take Attendance-Controller
app.controller('takeCtrl',takeCtrl);

//Define Controller
function takeCtrl($scope,$http){
  $scope.pageTitle='Attendance';

  //************INITIALIZE SOME VARIABLES AS REQUIRED*****
  $scope.view_btn='btn-danger';
  $scope.take_btn='btn-default';
  $scope.isTaking=true;
  $scope.isViewing=false;

    //SOME MORE CODE HERE

  } //CONTROLLER 1 ENDS


 //View Attendace-Controller
 app.controller('viewCtrl',viewCtrl);

//Define Controller
function viewCtrl($scope,$http){
    $scope.pageTitle='Attendance';

   //************INITIALIZE SOME VARIABLES AS REQUIRED*****
    $scope.view_btn='btn-default';
    $scope.take_btn='btn-danger';
    $scope.isTaking=false;
    $scope.isViewing=true;

     //SOME MORE CODE HERE

    } //CONTROLLER 2 ENDS
```

The views load just fine but the controller is the same.If I remove it from the body tag, there is no controller at all..

Comment: What do takeAttendance.html and viewAttendance.html look like? Usually, you can set your Angular controller inside those HTML files.

Comment: they actally contains a couple of <tr>s generated with ng-repeat. Setting the controller from there does renders the table correctly but all other variables outside the ng-view placeholder are not rendered...

Comment: What do you mean? What is rendered incorrectly?

Comment: Because router binds controller to ng-view element. So it sets ng-controller on table element basically. If you want entire body to be controlled by one or the other controller then I'de recommend to move this HTML to templates or use ng-include for these element that are supposed to be in both views.

Comment: @JohnBarton All the variables outside the ng-view...

Comment: @Keammoort That makes sense.. So how do I go about changing the elements outside the view ??

Comment: Move them inside two htmls you have in partials directory or move it to seperate file and use ng-include inside them to avoid copy-paste.

Comment: @Keammoort Well...My Title depends upon the view!!

Comment: I now, but angular binding would still work, so it'd change when controllers change

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding controller to a view in route provider, there is no need to use ng-controller.

```
<body ng-app='schoolConnect' >
```

Inject $location service to properly switch views.

```
viewCtrl($scope,$http,$location){
```

And use path method to switch to specified view:

```
$location.path('/take');
```

Then insert in index.html ng-view

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

In this div there would be views from route.